# Issues with CSS not seeming to find a class

Tags: html, css

I am writing a page in HTML and CSS. Inside the page, I have several `div` tags that I want to center on the page. I have wrapped them all in a `div` tag with the class `infogroup`. Then, to my CSS, I added this code: `.infogroup{text-align: center;}`. It does not center the text in my browser (google chrome), but it does in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TJonS/8xw9s). I am wondering why I am having this error, and what to do about it. The page has been tested locally and on a server, and has the trouble with both. [The page live:](http://apper.neocities.org/doc.html)

Thank you!

-Ty
**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>bridgeOrTunnel</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bot.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header><img src="botlogo.png"></header>
    <div class="infogroup">
    <div id="line1">
        <span class="image"><img src="bri.png"></span>
        <span class="image"><img src="tun.png"></span>
    </div>
    <div id="line2">
        <span class="time">9 minutes</span>
        <span class="time">13 minutes</span>
    </div>
    <div id="line3">
        <span class="lanes">3 lanes open</span>
        <span class="lanes">5 lanes open</span>
    </div>
    <div id="line4">
        <span class="cost">$1.39</span>
        <span class="cost">$4.27</span>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: please include your relevant html and css code here. Also when providing a jsfiddle it should be a fiddle displaying the problem not one that does not.

Comment: Got any code for us to see?

Comment: if it works in jsFiddle, then something else on your page is wrong or conflicting.  Please publish your page and post a link to it.

Comment: Looking at your code on the website you posted, there is no .infogroup {text-align:center; }

Comment: Your imported css don't contains instruction for .infogroup ([CSS](http://apper.neocities.org/bot.css))

Comment: I had two different versions of the same file. This was KILLING me!

Comment: @Willian Duarte, I just realized that. Thank you.

Comment: So, I just discovered my issue, with some help from the coders who commented. I had two different files with the same name in different locations. I was editing the one that was in a different location, thus messing it up. Caution to everyone else out there: **every file deserves a different name!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot to include this in your bot.css

```
.infogroup{
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: So, I just discovered my issue, with some help from the coders who commented. I had two different files with the same name in different locations. I was editing the one that was in a different location, thus messing it up. Caution to everyone else out there: **every file deserves a different name!**

Comment: hmm i knw,it happens sometimes we overlook few things while we are busy in coding. Never mind mate,the good thing is your problem is solved :)